# text file manipulations using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, awk

i have input data saved in a text file(input.txt) as given below

```
10    25 6 3    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1
```

i just need to increase the first row of 4th column value(3) by one after every 5 increment in first row of first column and i don't want to disturb second row
For example if i take above data as input then expected out put would be

```
10    25 6 3    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

11    25 6 3    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

12    25 6 3    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

13    25 6 3    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

14    25 6 3    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1
```

after that i want to increase the value of first row 4th column value by one so 3 would be 4 at that time out put should be as given below

```
15    25 6 4    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

16    25 6 4    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

17    25 6 4    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

18    25 6 4    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1

19    25 6 4    1   8   5   2   1   6  1
99    26 7 4    1   8   8   1   2   8  1
```

and so on ,my script is given below which  gives output but not upto my expectation,i hope i may get some idea from experts.

```
#!/bin/sh
for inc in $(seq 10 1 60)
do
  awk -vval=$inc '{
    if(NR==1) {
      $1=val
    } else $4=$4;
    print
  }' input.txt
echo '>>>>'
done
```

Comment: Posting "expected output" and then saying "after that..." and then posting other output is confusing. Do you want both sets of data output? If so should they go to separate files or what? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and the example, especially as it relates to having 2 separate sets of expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not that clear, this solution is completely based on your shown expected sample output only. Solution has 2 `awk` variables `times` means how many times you want to print whole file set and `thr` means what is the threshold on which you want to increase the value of 4th column in very first line of Input_file. If this is what you are not looking for then kindly do edit your question with more details.

```
awk -v times="10" -v thr="5" '
FNR==1{
  first=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  firstRest1=$1 OFS $2
  thirdField=$3
  $1=$2=$3=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  firstRest2=$0
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  ++count
  print first,firstRest1,thirdField,firstRest2 ORS val
  for(i=1;i<=times;i++){
    ++count
    print ++first,firstRest1,thirdField,firstRest2 ORS val
    if(count==(thr)){
      thirdField++
      count=""
    }
  }
}' Input_file | column -t
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP is requesting to get output into different output file for each iteration of whole content writing(blocks) so adding this solution, which will create output files like `output_file1`, `output_file2` and so on.

```
awk -v times="10" -v thr="5" '
FNR==1{
  first=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  firstRest1=$1 OFS $2
  thirdField=$3
  $1=$2=$3=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  firstRest2=$0
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  fileCnt=1
  output_file="output_file"fileCnt
  ++count
  print first,firstRest1,thirdField,firstRest2 ORS val > (output_file)
  for(i=1;i<=times;i++){
    ++count
    print ++first,firstRest1,thirdField,firstRest2 ORS val > (output_file)
    if(count==(thr)){
      thirdField++
      fileCnt++
      close(output_file)
      output_file="output_file"fileCnt
      count=""
    }
  }
}' Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223931/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-text-file-manipulations-using-shell-scri).